# SASS !default issue

Tags: css, sass

I have some trouble with my sass !default setup.

I have a default theme and some customize themes. Every customize theme should inherit the !default styles from the default theme.

Here some examples:

**default.scss**

```
/**
 * Colors
*/

$color-palette: (
  primary: #2196f3,
  brand: #2196f3, //deprecated
  secondary: #2a517f,
  highlight: #f3ae21,
  success: #c2e617,
  warning: #ffeb3b,
  danger: #f44336
 ) !default;

$color-primary: map-get($color-palette, primary) !default; 
$color-danger: map-get($color-palette, danger) !default; 
…

/**
 * Alerts
 * @param name - name of the property
 * @param color - background-color of the main div depending on the modifier
 * @param color - accent color of specific components depending on the modifier, e.g. border-right-color
 */

 $alert:(
   (default, $color-primary, $color-primary),
   …
 ) !default;
```

**custom-1.scss**

```
/**
 * Colors
*/

$color-palette: (
  primary: red,
  brand: blue,
  secondary: green,
  highlight: yellow,
  success: pink,
  warning: black,
  danger: white,
 );

 $alert:(
  (default, $color-danger, $color-danger),
   …
 );
```

In the custom-1.scss the compiler crashed -> `Undefined variable: "$color-danger".` The `$color-danger` is assigned in the default.scss but not in the custom-1.scss.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you import custom-1.scss after or before default.scss?

Comment: I tried both of them.